# Find substring and then extract preceding substring

Tags: sql-server

Been banging my head around this this morning.  Say I have a strings

- Model 389448937594 needed
- Hey, Model 3453535345353453453 needed
- I demand 35435453 needed

The key word here is "needed".  I can find that and the position but I'm having problem pulling the number preceding it which can vary in lenght.  I've tried variations of this and just not getting it.

```
Select Left(SubString(Notes, PatIndex('%needed%', Notes), 8000), PatIndex('%needed%', SubString(Notes, PatIndex('%needed%', Notes), 8000))+1)FROM ....WHERE ....
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or perhaps assist with the code?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For people in the future here was my final query.

Comment: better control of user input is the real solution

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is ugly, but it works:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('Model 389448937594 needed'),
                ('Hey, Model 3453535345353453453 needed'),
                ('I demand 35435453 needed')) A(string)
)


SELECT  string,
        REVERSE(LEFT(Data,CHARINDEX(' ',Data))) Model
FROM (  SELECT  REVERSE(LEFT(string,PATINDEX('%needed%',string)-2)) Data,
                string
        FROM CTE) A
```

The results are:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║                string                 ║        Model         ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ Model 389448937594 needed             ║         389448937594 ║
║ Hey, Model 3453535345353453453 needed ║  3453535345353453453 ║
║ I demand 35435453 needed              ║             35435453 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Im checking this out and tweaking for my exact needs.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, your cte and Zak's select got me going.  For some reason I couldn't get your select statement to work with my other cleanup.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple good answers here but this one might be easier to drop in your solution:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/930aa/35/0

```
SELECT 

REVERSE(
  SUBSTRING(
    SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Notes), PATINDEX('%dedeen %', REVERSE(Notes))+8, 8000),
    0,
    PATINDEX('% %',  
      SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Notes), PATINDEX('%dedeen %', REVERSE(Notes))+8, 8000)
     )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I did use this and Lamak's response to create the cte with all my notes.  For some reason I couldn't get his Select statement to work but your suggestion did. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @junk varchar(100)
set @junk = 'Model 12340928435903284567 needed'
set @junk = 'Model 1234 needed'
set @junk = 'Hey, Model 948530498567304958634 needed'

select ltrim(rtrim(reverse(substring(ltrim(substring(reverse(@junk), patindex('dedeen', reverse(@junk)) + 7, 1000)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', ltrim(substring(reverse(@junk), patindex('dedeen', reverse(@junk)) + 7, 1000)))))))
```

Comment out the different @junk assignments to see the different results.

Comment: Thanks however I should clarify that the word 'needed' can be anywhere in the string.  There could be a whole conversation after the word 'needed'.

Comment: Ah. Well... I still think using REVERSE() and messing a bit more with what I showed you, and you'll have a solution. Check out the CTE solution too... there's always more than one way to skin a cat. :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of REVERSE until today so definately something I'll remember and keep in the arsenal.  Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is actually answering my own question but i thought i'd give my final query from the awesome suggestions presented here.

```
with notes_cte (notes, account)
as
(
Select replace(CAST(Notes AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'  ',' '), Account_Id
FROM ....
where Notes like ('%needed%')
)

--select * from notes_cte

SELECT 

REVERSE(
SUBSTRING(
SUBSTRING(REVERSE(notes), PATINDEX('% dedeen%', REVERSE(notes))+11, 8000),
0,
PATINDEX('% %',  
  SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Notes), PATINDEX('% dedeen%', REVERSE(notes))+11, 8000)
 )
)
), account
FROM notes_cte
order by account
```

I had to add the REPLACE on the insert because I found some fields where people had inserted double spaces so I was getting blank results back.  Once the REPLACE was added all good.